# Can I get browsers to focus on these links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Fiddo](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/V5q8c/)

These links open in a new tab, but if you go back to the fiddle and click the other link, the browser doesn't switch your view to that tab. It reloads the "cool" tab to the other link, but I would like the browser to focus on the new tab.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="cool">google</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="cool">yahoo</a>
```

Comment: You can't force browsers to do that sort of thing. *edit* though if a tab launches an alert, some/most/all browsers will switch to that tab, which is a really horrible though possibly unavoidable interaction wart.

Comment: @Pointy I though as much, its kinda bullshit tho...

Comment: I don't know if you care if it opens multiple tabs, but you could give them different target names.

Comment: @varfoo ya, thats what im gonna do, but it was not my first choice option, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference another window, you need to save its reference in a variable.  Once you have that reference, you can manipulate it with `window` object functions.  For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Focus tab test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var cool;

            $("a").click(function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                if (typeof cool === "undefined") {
                    cool = window.open(this.href, "cool");
                } else {
                    cool.close();
                    cool = window.open(this.href, "cool");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/">microsoft</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></body>
</html>
```

Note that I can't make this a jsFiddle because they prevent you from opening tabs in their frames.  Also note that I had to destroy the old window and open a new one, rather than updating the location.href property and settings its focus.  That's because a JS doesn't have access to another window's properties unless the protocol (http), hostname and port all match.